# Avoid cascade div showing with javascript-jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my page does a simple verification if javascrit and cookies are enabled on client browser.
If yes, script shows div id="conteudo" (page content) and hide div id="aviso" (a kind of warning to enable features or reinstall browser in order to proceed).
If not, script keep div id="aviso" visible and hide div id="conteudo".

On my offline project all is working perfectly but on server that page seems to load a bit slow, when some of the conditions of script occurs (javascript or cookies disabled) I can see div id="aviso" for a fraction of second before desapear.
Its not a good experience as I planned. Anyone know how can I fix this in my code? Thank you.

```
var JS_Habilitado = false;
var C_Habilitado = false;

$(document).ready(function()
{
  //Teste do JavaScript (se entrou aqui, está habilitado).
  JS_Habilitado = true;
  //Teste dos cookies.
  var TEST_COOKIE = 'test_cookie';
  $.cookie(TEST_COOKIE, true);
  if ($.cookie(TEST_COOKIE))
  {
    $.cookie(TEST_COOKIE, null); //deletar o cookie.
    C_Habilitado = true;
  }
  //Avaliação final.
  if (JS_Habilitado&&C_Habilitado)
  {
    $("#aviso").hide();
    $("#conteudo").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#aviso").show(); 
    $("#conteudo").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You see this effect on all browsers but mainly in webkit based. Chrome and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

After including JQuery hide your elements:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#aviso").hide(); 
     $("#conteudo").hide();
 });
```

Or in css:

```
#aviso,#conteudo{display:none}
```

Comment: I can't hide #aviso on css beacuse if javascript is not enabled on client browser he will not see warning.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I can't mark not usefull and users think was answered. Do you want increase your level?